# Code for specific XML data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wpf

I need to generate this xml from a c# code however i m lost in  xmlwriter provided multiple writers.. Can anyone who got expertise in xml can help me out for writing C# code to produce this below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<Request xmlns="http://www.ABC.com/submit" xmlns:l="http://www.ABC.com/link" l:source="SRC" l:date="2014-03-05">
    <MyData l:identifier="PRAV" l:value="151.19448366182007269092408546">
        <DATA1 l:value="0.151328110447635" /> 
        <DATA2 l:value="0.6461191930062688087600920641" /> 
        <DATA3 l:value="0.144793773777417" /> 
    </MyData>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Paste Special](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/676330/Visual-Studio-Paste-Special-Feature) feature of Visual Studio.

With this you can copy your XML structure (provided it is valid which currently it isn't).

Select:

- Edit
- Paste Special
- Paste XML as Classes

This will give you a class representing your XML:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/submit")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/submit", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Request
{
    private RequestMyData myDataField;
    private string sourceField;
    private System.DateTime dateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RequestMyData MyData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.myDataField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link")]
    public string source
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sourceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sourceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link", DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dateField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/submit")]
public partial class RequestMyData
{
    private RequestMyDataDATA1 dATA1Field;
    private RequestMyDataDATA2 dATA2Field;
    private RequestMyDataDATA3 dATA3Field;
    private string identifierField;
    private decimal valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RequestMyDataDATA1 DATA1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dATA1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dATA1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public RequestMyDataDATA2 DATA2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dATA2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dATA2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public RequestMyDataDATA3 DATA3
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dATA3Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dATA3Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link")]
    public string identifier
    {
        get
        {
           return this.identifierField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.identifierField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link")]
    public decimal value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/submit")]
public partial class RequestMyDataDATA1
{
    private decimal valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link")]
    public decimal value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/submit")]
public partial class RequestMyDataDATA2
{
    private decimal valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link")]
    public decimal value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/submit")]
public partial class RequestMyDataDATA3
{
    private decimal valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.ABC.com/link")]
    public decimal value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write your  classes as DataContracts and assigns XML attributes to the DataMembers you should be able to get what you need.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Request
    {
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
        public string Source { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public MyData MyData { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MyData
    {
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
        public double Value { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Data> Datum { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and to test

```
    var listOfData = new List<Data> {new Data {Value = 0.15}, new Data {Value = 0.64}};
        var myData = new MyData {Identifier = "PRAV", Value = 151.194, Datum = listOfData};
        var request = new Request {MyData = myData, Source = "SRC"};
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ser.Serialize(sw, request);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
```

Thiis will result in

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
 <Request
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http:/ /www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Source="SRC">   
      <MyData Identifier="PRAV" Value="151.194">
           <Datum>
                <Data Value="0.15" />
                <Data Value="0.64" />
           </Datum>   
      </MyData> 
 </Request>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XDocument` to create XML file from C# :

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", ""));    
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ABC.com/submit";
XNamespace l = "http://www.ABC.com/link";

        //<Request>
doc.Add(new XElement(ns+"Request",
            //xmlns="http://www.ABC.com/submit"
            new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.ABC.com/submit"),
            //xmlns:l="http://www.ABC.com/link"
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "l", "http://www.ABC.com/link"),
            //l:source="SRC"
            new XAttribute(l+"source", "SRC"),
            //l:date="2014-03-05"
            new XAttribute(l + "date", "2014-03-05"),
            //<MyData>
            new XElement(ns+"MyData",
                //l:identifier="PRAV" 
                new XAttribute(l+"identifier", "PRAV"),
                //l:value="151.19448366182007269092408546"
                new XAttribute(l + "value", "151.19448366182007269092408546"),
                //<DATA1> 
                new XElement(ns+"DATA1",
                    //l:value="0.151328110447635"
                    new XAttribute(l + "value", "0.151328110447635")),
                //<DATA2> 
                new XElement(ns+"DATA2",
                    //l:value="0.6461191930062688087600920641"
                    new XAttribute(l + "value", "0.6461191930062688087600920641")),
                //<DATA3> 
                new XElement(ns+"DATA3",
                    //l:value="0.144793773777417"
                    new XAttribute(l + "value", "0.144793773777417")))));
doc.Save("xml_name.xml");
```